# How to add Canon printer that works on Windows machines?

Tags: macos, printing, driver, canon

I'm trying to add a `Canon MF8050cn` to print from OS X Yosemite that works fine from `Windows 7` machines.  I installed the `Canon 8000` driver [Mac_MF_Ver1040_00.dmg](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/color_imageclass_mf8050cn) for Macintosh.  I can ping the printer successfully at `10.1.10.18` from my Macintosh.  In the Add Printer dialog on the Macintosh, I enter the static IP address of the printer and `Internet Printing Protocol` and use `Canon MF8000 Series`, however, when I click `Add` on the dialog, it gives the error:

```
Unable to verify the printer on your network.
Unable to connect to '10.1.10.18' due to an error.
Would you still like to create the printer?
```

Choosing `Continue` gives a printer that when you print to it gets the error `Printing - The printer is not responding.`

How can I configure this printer for access from my Macintosh?

Comment: Did you try using the Canon driver for the Mac? The file is
   "Mac_MF_Ver1040_00.dmg"
http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/color_imageclass_mf8050cn

Comment: @CharlesLindsay Yes this is the driver I have already installed when I get to this issue described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo have to download and install the Canon Drivers.

You can find the drivers for your printer [here](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/color_imageclass_mf8050cn#DriversAndSoftware).

From the [printer manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300002527/03/MF8050Cn_STARTER_en-us_R_2.pdf):

- Installing the software:

[image]

- Bonjour connection:

[image]

- TCP/IP connection:

[image]

Comment: This is true I have a Canon Printer as well and I have to set it up through Canon's driver.

Comment: I did install the driver, that is how I got to this point where the `Canon MF8000 Series` appears in the apple printer setup dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem with a Canon Printer and OSX El Capitan 10.11.2. I found out from Canon's website that I needed to specify Line Printer Daemon (LPD) as the Protocol instead of Internet Printing Protocol (IPP) which was selected by default. After selecting LPD, there was no "Unable to connect to ... due to an error. Would you still like to create the printer?" message, and my print jobs finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

As with many modern printers, you'll probably have an easier setup if it's set to auto-IP configuration, getting an IP address from your router rather than you manually choosing one. A manual setup *should* also work but as it's not working for you under OS X you may as well let Bonjour do the hard work - as far as I know IPP isn't supported on your printer so this may explain the error you receive.

You then want to install the printer driver using the Bonjour protocol as this will detect the printer regardless of its allocated IP address. In the Add Printer dialogue box your Canon should appear in the "Default" list, with its network name in the left column and "Bonjour" in the Kind column. All you should need to do then is select the appropriate driver from the Print Using pull-down menu, and the unit *should* be good to go.